# Internet Explorer doesn't show an image

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a problem with my website, the Yellow Butterfly Logo doesn't show up in Internet Explorer, but does in Chrome and other browsers.

I don't even know where the problem is so I couldn't find anything out.

If you need more information tell me; here is the [Website](http://zitronenfalter-spa.at) (to see the problem open with).

```
#logo
{
    z-index:2333;
    position:absolute;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    margin-left:-375px;
    margin-top:-24px;   
}
```

Sorry for my bad English its not my native language.

Comment: You should fix up your containers to not need absolute positioning anymore. Try `float:left` for both the logo and the main headline and place the logo inside your `#oberdiv`.

Comment: Please don't put `[tags]` in the title of your question, and don't worry about your 'bad English,' so long as we can understand your question we'll try to help. But, importantly, which version(s) of IE?

Comment: You also have invalid HTML which is going to give you all kinds of issues with Internet Explorer.  See:  http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zitronenfalter-spa.at&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your positioning is a mess. You give the logo `absolute` positioning, but then specify none of the positioning properties (left/top/right/bottom) - this makes the resultant position of your image undefined by the CSS standards. Chrome/Firefox default to `left:50%` in this case, IE to `left:0`.

Make it explicit, by adding `left:50%` to your CSS rule for `#logo`, and the image will appear in IE again.

I would recommend reading up some more about how the box model actually works though, your site is *really* a mess right now and it's a miracle it's working as good as it does right now.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here appears to be default placement of an absolutely positioned element within an element using the `align` attribute such as `<div align='center'>...</div>`. Chrome allows the `align` attribute to center an absolutely-positioned element, where as Internet Explorer 11 does not.

After checking the *in-development* version of Internet Explorer via http://remote.modern.ie, it appears future versions Internet Explorer will handle this in the same way Chrome does, making the following solution relevant only for backwards compatibility.

Apply the following changes to address the problem:

```css
div#wrapper {
    width: 768px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

By setting `width: 768px` on the `#wrapper` and `margin: 0 auto` we take a better approach to centering your layout, as well as positioning aboslutely-positioned children.

```css
#logo {
    /* margin-left: -375 */
}
```

All that is needed now is to remove the above rule. Due to the improved centering, we no longer need to specify the left margin.

In the long-run, I would encourage you to not rely on margins at all for positioned absolutely-positioned elements. Instead, the would use more explicit absolute coordinates:

```css
#logo {
    left: 0;
    top: 187px;
}
```

Here's a change-summary from Internet Explorer's F12 Developer Tools that show a diff:

[image: Internet Explorer Changes]

Comment: This is the better *approach* for sure, but from what I've seen this will break most of his site. Right now just adding `left:50%` to the logo is the only viable solution until the rest is fixed.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes What does this break?

Comment: He's using a complete hit&miss approach with global centering, and then adds a lot of random `position:relative` and `position:absolute` rules to elements that aren't fitting the flow. That's bound to break positioning contexts in a few places. It may just work though with these small fixes, but that's more luck than anything else on his part.

Don't get me wrong, I'm all for fundamentally fixing it, but there's a lot more broken than just `div#header`.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Granted the site could be built *better*, but I don't see anything *breaking* on account of my suggested fixes.